# How to create a column based of parsed element of other column

Tags: powerquery

I am looking to create a brand new column, that uses a value split from another column:

Example:

Column1
99-DDESRT

Column2
99

So basically i need a column generated that uses the left most portion of a '-' delimiter split

Answer (score 0):

Add column .. custom column ... with formula

```
= Text.BeforeDelimiter([Column1], "-")
```

In a second alternate method, Right click the column and duplicate column.
Right click the new column, split column ... by delimiter ... choose custom type in first box on top and **-** in second box, and [x] leftmost delimiter then hit [OK]